# Submitting Form with jQuery AJAX to the required PHP POST request handler is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Whenever I submit a from using jquery ajax to an PHP api the form is not submitting to the required **post request handler**. But when I submit the form basically, I mean without using an javascript or jquery the form is submit and it is redirecting to a php page with json response.

**Note** No problems with CORS here the CORS are fine as I have allowed cross-site requests in the api.

Below is my **login.html** file.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/style.css">
    <script src="./assets/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <title>User Login Page</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="header">
        <h2>Login</h2>
    </div>

    <form action="http://localhost/auth-app/server.php" method="post">
        <div class="input-group">
            <label for="">Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <label for="">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" required>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Login" name="login" class="submit-btn">
        </div>
        <p>
            Not yet a member? <a href="register.html">Register</a>
        </p>
    </form>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // submit login form with ajax
            $('form').submit(function (event) {
                /* stop form from submitting normally */
                event.preventDefault();
                $(".submit-btn").click(function () {
                    $.post("http://localhost/auth-app/server.php", {
                        email: $('#email').val(),
                        password: $('#password').val()
                    },
                        function (data, status) {
                            const json = $.parseJSON(data);
                            console.log("Data: " + typeof(json) + "\nStatus: " + status);
                        });
                });
            });
        });


    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Note** What I want is to be able to submit the form to the **required PHP post request handler function** using jquery ajax.

Below is my **server.php** api file.

```php
$errors = array();

// login
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
    $email = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $password = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

    if (empty($email)) {
        array_push($errors, 'Email is required');
    }
    if (empty($password)) {
        array_push($errors, 'Password is required');
    }

    if (count($errors) == 0) {

                // log user in
                $data = ['success_login' => 'true'];
                header('Content-type: application/json');
                echo json_encode(null);
        } else {
            array_push($errors, 'The email or password is incorrect');
            // after entering wrong credentials
            $data = ['success_login' => 'false'];
            header('Content-type: application/json');
            echo json_encode($data);
        }
}
```

In **debug console** I'm getting the error bellow.
**Note** this is just proof that the post request is not reaching the php post request handler in the in the api file.

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

What I'm expecting to get in the console is json data like below:

```
success_login   "true"
```

**!IMPORTANT INFO:**
I'm not very experienced with php but I have noticed that when submitting form without using any javascript eg jquery or ajax the form submits successfully because the name of the submit button eg `<input type="submit" value="Login" name="login">` is the same as the name inside `$_POST['login']`. But when submitting form using ajax technically you don't use that button to submit.

So how do I solve this problem? Thank you posted with Love.

Comment: Well then check for one of the other parameters that _do_ get send then, instead of the login button?

Comment: Your attempt to validate the parameters is the wrong way around, btw. You are trying to access `$_POST['email']`, before checking if _that_ is even set.

Comment: Since you see SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data. The Ajax and PHP work and the response comes back to the client. Maybe, "echo json_encode(null);" on count($errors) == 0. It should be  echo json_encode($data);

Comment: There is one extra  `}` in login.php. Just remove the last `}`. :-)

Comment: @Jagveer An extra `}` is just here but not in original code. I must have put it here by mistake!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below code

```
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $('form').submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(".submit-btn").click(function () {

         name: $('#email').val(),
         password: $('#password').val()

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'http://localhost/auth-app/server.php',
            data: {
                name: name,
                password : password,
                action: 'login'
            },
            success: function(response) {

            }
        })
    });
    });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to declare the click button event as you are already using the form submit button event. Also, add the **login** key as the parameter value in **$.post**, as you are checking it's isset value in **login.php** file.

Also, note that there is extra closes braces **"}"** in your **login.php** file